# If $n$ is pseudo prime to $2 \in Z_n$, then $N = 2^n -1$ is a pseudo-prime to $2 \in Z_N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pseudoprimes

> If $n$ is pseudo prime to $2 \in Z_n$, then $N = 2^n -1$ is a
> pseudo-prime to $2 \in Z_N$.

Attempt: By definition, $n$ being a pseudoprime to $2$ in $Z_n$ means $2^{n-1} - 1 = nk$ for some integer $k$. I am not sure where to go with this.

Comment: I definitely recommend working on this problem in terms of congrences (modular arithmetic) instead of explicit factorizations. Can you write what congruence you are given, and what congruence you need to prove? Can you evaluate $2^n\pmod N$? What is the other property that a number must have to be a pseudoprime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $N:=2^n-1$.
HINT: $$2^{n-1} \equiv_n 1 \ \implies \ 2^n \equiv_n 2$$
$$\implies n|(2^n -2) \implies n|(N-1)$$
$$\implies (2^n-1)|(2^{N-1}-1)$$
$$\implies N|(2^{N-1}-1) \implies 2^{N-1} \equiv_{N} 1.$$